# Ajax call doesn't work properly in Chrome and FF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax, cross-browser

I'm trying to change a div's content by calling a partial view with jQuery, from another partial view.
Here's the patial view From which I'm trying to invoke the second one:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<div id="Bar">Content goes here
</div>
<div id="Register">Register</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Register').click(function () {

        var resultHTML = jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'AccountBar/Register'
        }).responseText;
        $('#Bar').html(resultHTML);       
    });
});
```

This works well in IE(9) but not in Chrome nor in FF - both just empty the "Bar" div.
When debugging in browser, it seems resultHTML is empty in both Chrome and FF (but in IE it's correct).
When debugging in VS, all clicks on register div call the correct action:

```
public PartialViewResult Register()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

And the view:

```
@model PartialTry.Models.PasswordModel
    <h2>Register</h2>
```

Any idea how to get Chrome and FF to change "Bar" div as well?
Thanks.

Comment: Try working with the AJAX callback methods, maybe only IE9 support the synchronous AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing this:

```
var resultHTML = jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'AccountBar/Register'
}).responseText;
$('#Bar').html(resultHTML);
```

IE9 is doing a little trickery here, blocking until the request completes (or caching it, depending on which build you're on) when accessing `.responseText`.  The important thing to remember is it's an **asynchronous** call, meaning it goes off and makes the request...the *result* will be available later.

In this case the simplest approach is [the `.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) just for this:

```
$('#Bar').load('AccountBar/Register');
```

This roughly translates into:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'AccountBar/Register'
    success: function(result) {
        $('#Bar').html(result);
    }
});
```

---

The alternative approach like that you're attempting is to make the request * synchronous* (please **don't do this**) by [setting `async: false` on the `$.ajax({})` call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), like this:

```
var resultHTML = jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'AccountBar/Register',
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

This will work...but it'll also **lock up the browser** while it runs, instead of causing no interruption and updating `#Bar` when complete...this is a much worse user experience, and best not to do it.

Comment: ... whoa wait - *why* is IE9 blocking? I haven't had any coffee yet but I don't get it ... is it just a hack built into the XHR object?

Comment: @Pointy - The caching mechanism is different there, if you're made the request before it'll go "hey wait I got that in cache, un momento", they may have reverted this behavior in the final (hence the disclaimer above) but the beta was doing some funky optimization with XHR there.

Comment: Ah OK well I get it when the URL maps into the cache; that makes sense ... and I can *imagine* a dependency analysis trick causing blocking behavior, but that seems like an absolutely terrible idea. I mean, it'll make some less well-informed developers happy, I guess.

Comment: @Pointy - "that seems like an absolutely terrible idea", which part, IE9 itself or the XHR behavior? :)

Comment: ha ha :-)  Well effectively making the ajax calls synchronous (automatically and silently) is what I meant.

Comment: @Pointy - I *think* it only did this when it had them in cache or partially in cache (another tab loading it), but I didn't do extensive testing...more of "well it's beta, *surely* they'll fix it"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried waiting for a response via callback?  For example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET', 
  url: 'AccountBar/Register',
  context: document.body,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#Bar').html(response);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert('oops, something went wrong!')
  }
});
```